# How to find port number on FTP server installed on IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 R2

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, ftps

I have installed a FTP Client on my local machine and I would like to transfer/upload files from my local to a remote server(Windows 2008 R2 with FTP installed on it). How can I find the port number on the remote server? Please note that I have full admin privileges on the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default TCP FTP ports are 21 for communication and 20 for data transfer.

Comment: Hi rekire. Thanks for that! I am trying to upload data to a production server(remote). I am using Filezilla FTP client on my local with host and the port as 20. It says Connection timed out. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to use the default Port 21. About your tags you use ftp and not ftps right?

Comment: i did not use any tags actually

Comment: Is there anything that I have to enable from remote server?

Comment: Sorry I was afk did you open the firewall?

Comment: please check http://morndej.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/how-to-add-windows-2008-firewall-rule-to-allow-active-ftp-client/